# Can't Allow Specific Port in Windows Firewall Advanced Security - Windows 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, firewall

In the Outbound Rules, I set up a rule to allow outbound connection from port 26. But, it doesn't work.

However, if I allow "all port" for this rule, this will work, but then all ports will be allowed too.

What is the reason? Is there any conflicting rule? I need to fix this as soon as possible.

-Edit to add :

I'm trying to allow email access to mail server outside (port 26). The thing is, even if I telnet using port 26, it will not work, unless I allow "all ports". Specific port will not do.

Comment: What are you actually trying to allow access to? It sounds to me like port 26 is being opened fine, but that whatever you are trying to use needs access to other ports too (or instead)

Comment: I'm trying to allow email access to mail server outside (port 26). The thing is, even if I telnet using port 26, it will not work, unless I allow "all ports". Specific port will not do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're connecting TO port 26 not FROM port 26, so the rule should allow connections FROM any port TO port 26.

Comment: Oh, wow.. Okay.. It's the local port and remote port that I don't understand.. It's working now.. But I'm still confused, why should the local port to be "ALL PORTS".. Thanks

Comment: Because the local side will select a random port from one of the ephemeral ports to make the outbound connection from. http://www.ncftp.com/ncftpd/doc/misc/ephemeral_ports.html

Comment: Glad to help...